# How to load and evaluate a CNN using a test set in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a CNN on a set of images. There are 2 folders: training_set and test_set, each containing 2 classes.
They look like this:

```
training_set/
    classA/
        img1.png
        img2.png
        ...
    classB/
        img1.png
        img2.png
        ...
```

```
test_set/
    classA/
        img1.png
        img2.png
        ...
    classB/
        img1.png
        img2.png
        ...
```

Code looks like this, where the training set is split into a training and validation set:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

# Set image properties
img_height = 369
img_width = 496
batch_size = 32

# Import data set from directory
train_images = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "path_to_training_set",
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode="binary", # not sure about this one though, as the classes are not called '0' and '1'
    class_names = ['classA', 'classB'],
    color_mode =  'rgb',
    batch_size = batch_size,
    image_size = (img_height, img_width),
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 123,
    validation_split = 0.2,
    subset = "training"
)

val_images = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "path_to_training_set",
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode="binary", # not sure about this one though, as the classes are not called '0' and '1'
    class_names = ['classA', 'classB'],
    color_mode =  'rgb',
    batch_size = batch_size,
    image_size = (img_height, img_width),
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 123,
    validation_split = 0.2,
    subset = "validation"
)
```

Then:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

img_height = 369
img_width = 496
epochs = 25

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Since we have two classes:
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# BinaryCrossentropy because there are 2 classes 
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False), metrics=['accuracy'])

# Feed the model
history = model.fit(train_images, epochs=epochs, batch_size=32, verbose=1, validation_data=val_images)

# Plot
acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
epochs_range = range(epochs)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.show()
```

Now that the model is trained, it shows plots of the training and validation accuracy and loss. I try to load my test set using:

```
test_images = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "path_to_test_set",
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode="binary",
    class_names = ['classA', 'classB'],
    color_mode =  'rgb',
    batch_size = batch_size, # not really applicable as I want to use the whole set?
    image_size = (img_height, img_width),
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 123,
    validation_split = None
)
```

But is this the correct way? How do I deal with the batch_size? I think I'd evaluate the model with my test set using:

```
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, verbose=2)
print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

but I don't think this is sufficient as I'd like the accuracy, precision, recall and F1-score. I'm also not even sure the right thing is happening here (with how the test set is loaded).

So basically: How do I load my test set and calculate accuracy, precision, recall and F1-score?

Comment: You can get the labels from tf.data and compare them with the model predictions.

Comment: Ok, I tried this now: `y_prob = model.predict(test_images) 
y_classes = y_prob.argmax(axis=-1)`, but y_classes return all 0. How do I get the correct labels corresponding to the predictions made (as model.predict returns different values every run)?

Comment: I added an answer. Please mark it as accepted if it solves your problem. If not let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the data, then you can collect predictions and true classes.

```
predicted_probs = np.array([])
true_classes =  np.array([])

for images, labels in test_images:
  predicted_probs = np.concatenate([predicted_probs,
                       model(images)])
  true_classes = np.concatenate([true_classes, labels.numpy()])
```

Since they are sigmoid outputs, you need to transform them into classes with a threshold, i.e 0.5 here:

```
predicted_classes = [1 * (x[0]>=0.5) for x in predicted_probs]
```

After that you can get the confusion matrix etc:

```
conf_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(true_classes, predicted_classes)
```