# How to create a confusion matrix for VGG16 image calssification (2 options) when using preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: python, keras, confusion-matrix

I have been trying to create a confusion matrix to test my data on from my VGG16 classification model (python 3.8, using Keras).

I found a boiler plate based off of datagenerator. I tried leaving the test data as datagenerator, however then it always picks the first option. I tried converting my data coming in to data gen and ran into all sorts of problems.

(edit 02AUG2021)
Now I am trying to fit the confusion matrix to my preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory and I get

```
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Here is my code (the directory has been changed as I don't want it on the internet)
(new code)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import itertools
import sklearn
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from tensorflow.keras import layers


#Importing images
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    'directory\\classification', 
    labels="inferred", 
    label_mode="binary", 
    class_names=None, 
    color_mode="rgb", 
    batch_size=16, 
    image_size=(227, 227), 
    shuffle=True, 
    seed=50, 
    validation_split=0.2, 
    subset="training", 
    interpolation="bilinear", 
    follow_links=False,  
)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    'directory\\classification', 
    labels="inferred", 
    label_mode="binary", 
    class_names=None, 
    color_mode="rgb", 
    batch_size=16, 
    image_size=(227, 227), 
    shuffle=True, 
    seed=50, 
    validation_split=0.2, 
    subset="validation", 
    interpolation="bilinear", 
    follow_links=False,  
)

test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    'directory\\test', 
    labels="inferred", 
    label_mode="binary", 
    class_names=None, 
    color_mode="rgb", 
    batch_size=16, 
    image_size=(227, 227), 
    shuffle=False, 
    seed=50, 
    validation_split=None, 
    subset=None, 
    interpolation="bilinear", 
    follow_links=False,  
)

print("Number of training samples: %d" % tf.data.experimental.cardinality(train_ds))
print("Number of validation samples: %d" % tf.data.experimental.cardinality(val_ds))
print("Number of test samples: %d" % tf.data.experimental.cardinality(test_ds))

# Visualise the data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
    for i in range(9): 
        ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1) 
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8")) 
        plt.title(int(labels[i])) 
        plt.axis("off")

# data augmentation
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"), 
     layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),])

# Visualise
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, _ in train_ds.take(1):
    for i in range(9):
        augmented_images = data_augmentation(images)
        ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(augmented_images[0].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.axis("off")

# buffered prefetching - last op on dataset, suggested 2xbatch, default batch =32
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=32)
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=32)
test_ds = test_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=32)

# build the model
base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
    include_top=False,  # Do not include the ImageNet classifier at the top.
    weights="imagenet",   # Load weights pre-trained on ImageNet.
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=(227, 227, 3),
    pooling=max,
    classes=2,
    classifier_activation="softmax") 

# Freeze the base_model
base_model.trainable = False

# Create new model on top
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(227, 227, 3))
x = data_augmentation(inputs)  # Apply random data augmentation (GPU method)

# Pre-trained Imagenet weights requires that input be normalized
# from (0, 255) to a range (-1., +1.), the normalization layer
# does the following, outputs = (inputs - mean) / sqrt(var)
norm_layer = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization()
mean = np.array([127.5] * 3)
var = mean ** 2
# Scale inputs to [-1, +1]
x = norm_layer(x)
norm_layer.set_weights([mean, var])

# The base model contains batchnorm layers. We want to keep them in inference mode
# when we unfreeze the base model for fine-tuning, so we make sure that the
# base_model is running in inference mode here.
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)  # Regularize with dropout
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.summary()

#train the top layer
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()],
)

history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=2, validation_data=val_ds)

#Evaluate model
validation_steps = 20

loss0,accuracy0 = model.evaluate(val_ds, steps = validation_steps)

print("loss: {:.2f}".format(loss0))
print("accuracy: {:.2f}".format(accuracy0))

#learning curves
# accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['binary_accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_binary_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

#loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

#confusion matrix
# You need to iterate over the data, then you can collect predictions and true classes.
predicted_probs = np.empty([])
true_classes =  np.empty([])

for images, labels in test_ds:
  predicted_probs = np.concatenate([predicted_probs,
                       model(images)])
  true_classes = np.concatenate([true_classes, labels.numpy()])

# Since they are sigmoid outputs, you need to transform them into classes with a threshold, i.e 0.5 here:
predicted_classes = [1 * (x[0]>=0.5) for x in predicted_probs]

# confusion matrix etc:
conf_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(true_classes, predicted_classes)
print(conf_matrix)
```

I am struggling. I know that there is an issue with the prefect dataset, but I don't know how to fix. I tried classes, class_names, labels. I can't find things to help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I have been attempting to get this working using data generators since there were examples. I have managed to get a confusion matrix working with this method.
However, I am unsure about my conversion of predicted values to binary. I tried using argmax and it said everything was 0 (out of 0 or 1). I have found an alternate method to convert the binarized values and it appears to be working, but I don't understand it and I am worried I have cocked up.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import itertools
import sklearn
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

#Importing images
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.2)

train_ds = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'directory\\classification',
    target_size=(227, 227),
    batch_size=16,
    color_mode="rgb",
    subset="training",
    seed=50,
    class_mode="binary",
    shuffle=True)

val_ds = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'directory\\classification',
    target_size=(227, 227),
    batch_size=16,
    color_mode="rgb",
    subset="validation",
    seed=50,
    class_mode="binary",
    shuffle=True)

test_generator = ImageDataGenerator()
test_data_generator = test_generator.flow_from_directory(
    'directory\\test',   # Put your path here
    target_size=(227, 227),
    batch_size=16,
    color_mode="rgb",
    shuffle=False)


# Visualise the data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


# data augmentation
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"), 
     layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),])



# build the model
base_model = keras.applications.VGG16(
    include_top=False,  # Do not include the ImageNet classifier at the top.
    weights="imagenet",   # Load weights pre-trained on ImageNet.
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=(227, 227, 3),
    pooling=max,
    classes=2,
    classifier_activation="softmax") 

# Freeze the base_model
base_model.trainable = False

# Create new model on top
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(227, 227, 3))
x = data_augmentation(inputs)  # Apply random data augmentation (GPU method)

# Pre-trained Imagenet weights requires that input be normalized
# from (0, 255) to a range (-1., +1.), the normalization layer
# does the following, outputs = (inputs - mean) / sqrt(var)
norm_layer = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization()
mean = np.array([127.5] * 3)
var = mean ** 2
# Scale inputs to [-1, +1]
x = norm_layer(x)
norm_layer.set_weights([mean, var])

# The base model contains batchnorm layers. We want to keep them in inference mode
# when we unfreeze the base model for fine-tuning, so we make sure that the
# base_model is running in inference mode here.
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)  # Regularize with dropout
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.summary()

#train the top layer
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()],
)

history =model.fit_generator(train_ds, 
    steps_per_epoch=train_ds.samples / train_ds.batch_size, 
    epochs=34, 
    validation_data=val_ds,
    validation_steps=val_ds.samples / val_ds.batch_size,
    verbose=1)

# Unfreeze the base_model. Note that it keeps running in inference mode
# since we passed `training=False` when calling it. This means that
# the batchnorm layers will not update their batch statistics.
# This prevents the batchnorm layers from undoing all the training
# we've done so far.

# Fine tuning
base_model.trainable = True
model.summary()

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-5),  # Low learning rate
    loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()],
)

# fit_generator() is normally useful if you cannot fit your data into your main → ResourceExhaustedError:
history = model.fit_generator(train_ds, 
    steps_per_epoch=train_ds.samples / train_ds.batch_size, 
    epochs=17 , 
    validation_data=val_ds,
    validation_steps=val_ds.samples / val_ds.batch_size,
    verbose=1)


#Evaluate model
validation_steps = 20

loss0,accuracy0 = model.evaluate(val_ds, steps = validation_steps)

print("loss: {:.2f}".format(loss0))
print("accuracy: {:.2f}".format(accuracy0))

#learning curves
# accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['binary_accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_binary_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

#loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

#confusion matrix
#1.Predict classes
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

test_steps_per_epoch = np.math.ceil(test_data_generator.samples / test_data_generator.batch_size)

predictions = model.predict_generator(test_data_generator, steps=test_steps_per_epoch)

# Get most likely class
predicted_classes = [1 * (x[0]>=0.5) for x in predictions]

# 2.Get ground-truth classes and class-labels
true_classes = test_data_generator.classes
class_labels = list(test_data_generator.class_indices.keys()) 

# 3. Use scikit-learn to get statistics
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,classification_report

print(class_labels)

print(confusion_matrix(test_data_generator.classes, predicted_classes))

report = sklearn.metrics.classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)
```

This returns a matrix of (rows = true, columns = predicted)

```
[[3998     2]
 [   5  3995]]
```

Comment: You can get labels by iterating over the dataset.

Comment: Hi Frightera, How do you iterate over the dataset?

Comment: `image_dataset_from_directory` returns a `tf.data.Dataset`. So you can get labels with `for x, y in train_ds: ...` where y corresponds to labels.

Comment: Uh, Frightera, you might need to be more specific or provide an example. I don't know where you got your info from. I am reading <tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset> after you comment and cannot find it. I am pretty lost. The method test_ds.labels returns that `AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'labels'`

Comment: Check this answer to see an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68018762/how-to-load-and-evaluate-a-cnn-using-a-test-set-in-tensorflow/68033442#68033442

Comment: cheers Frightera, I will suss it out tomorrow.

Comment: Frigtera I have tried it and I get an issue with concatonate
  `File "<ipython-input-64-bdc02e26a1d0>", line 5, in <module>
    predicted_probs = np.concatenate([predicted_probs,

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)`

Comment: Instead of `np.array()` try `np.empty()`.

Comment: hey Frightera I used a softmax function, and in your example you used a sigmoid. do I keep the same predicted classes?

Comment: Your model has `binary_crossentropy` with one neuron? Can you edit the question with the latest code?

Comment: Frightera, now I get with `np.empty` the error
 `ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated `

Comment: I have used `binary crossentropy` because there are only two categories. I am not sure about the one neuron thing, I just used the VGG16 base model and tried to use an example off of the Keras site as a boilerplate. I will update in a moment, running another test. I have been trying two methods concurrently to try to not waste time. I am only running 1-2 epochs untill I get the model right, then I will increase the epochs and add some fine tuning

Comment: Frightera I have updated the code and put in my alternate method (using the generators)